# What color to choose as "danger" if the main color of my app is red

Tags: website-design, gui-design, color-scheme

I'm having this question wrapped around my head for quite some time. The thing is that my main application has a red color theme. And for just cancel buttons I used to use just gray colors but now that I need a "danger" color... What should I use? Purple? Orange? Using the red again is awkward, maybe a darker red?

PD: I cannot use blue because it's our competitors color.

[image]

Comment: [Mauve.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vHld_WlIPM) ;-)

Comment: Red is a warning colour only in (some) western cultures.   I believe far eastern cultures use red to mean wealth or money.   Bottom line (as the answers show) is to not use only colours, but icons and text for a lot of UI.

Comment: you need both a color AND another thing : many, many persons are color blind (in several variants)...

Comment: Looking at the icons you posted in your question, I would be nervous to click Save and comfortable clicking Delete (I'm from the US).  Is the red color theme central to your brand, or can you change it?  If you plan to market your app in the US, you'll have to work really hard to work against the stress that the color red tends to invoke there.  However if your target market is elsewhere, then it may be a non-issue.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will use green on "save" and yellow on "delete". Red themes are so difficult to work with...

Comment: If the main color of your app is red then your entire app is screaming DANGER at the user all the time.

Comment: Yellow should do it.

Comment: @Neil: These colour-meaning-by-culture mappings only ever go so far. Yes, there are strong connotations of the colour red with good luck e.g. in China. Still, red means "stop" on traffic lights over there, as well, and image-googling for "China warning sign" gives a fair number of results that very much use the colour red to indicate danger or a prohibition of something. At the end of the day, bright, saturated red (and yellow, and orange, for that matter) are not warning colours for cultural reasons, but because they simply stick out visually in most natural and artificial surroundings.

Comment: I think it is mostly important that there is contrast between your warning/error and your application. You should also avoid using colors that are commonly established to mean something else. I would also be careful with red, or at least offer a colorblind-friendly mode if at all feasible. I know of several people who cannot see red, and looking at certain shades of it actually physically hurt them. Not an answer, but still something to keep in mind.

Comment: Coke! No Pepsi!

Comment: How has no-one suggested looking to YouTube as a reference point for this? Their whole scheme is red and shades of gray (with small bits of Google signature Blue). I mean, even their Subscribe buttons and little "HD" alerts (both GOOD things) are red.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I think you need to play around. If your screens are red and you are about to use a warning or Danger. I have the following suggestions:

1- You can still **use red but in different degree** in order to differentiate between the app color and your danger action.

2- You can **use pure white popup and, apply red icons**, exclamation mark or signs within this popup.

3- Another suggestion is to **use black color, and use white signs over the black popup**. This may be a change.

If you can provide us with a screen of your red system, I can give you a straight forward solution.

[image]

Comment: I like how the the black text on white option looks, but the white on black really stands out.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I think the alternative for red is black for danger. Not other color.

Comment: Nature's warning colour is black stripes on yellow: "I sting". Black text on yellow ground is used for much warning signage.

Comment: using yellow and black it could be a solution but I think it will be overwhelming and more for construction I think. Also, it will not match the red theme as the owner suggested to use.

Comment: In Europe, Black is used as a more dangerous color than red at least for the Piste color scheme: Green, Blue, Red, Black [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piste).

Comment: @Khalil_Hanna Tone it down as much as you think appropriate. I can imagine the above black on white pop-up with a fairly fine diagonally striped yellow-and-black border. Or the ground of the circular shriek as yellow, on the pop-up with the black ground.

Comment: This could be an option!

Comment: @xiota, I think making the white text slightly larger (or perhaps bolder) should make it easier to read

Answer (score 55):

Rather than focusing just on the colour of the button, it's better to focus on the experience as a whole for that particular task. You don't necessarily need a separate danger colour for a delete button. You can use your standard red button, but support it with other danger messaging. Like this:

[image]

If your user is about to do something dangerous, it's better to use an alert and messaging to highlight the danger, rather than just rely on button colour.

It's also worth saying that there's nothing inherently dangerous or scary about a red app. I designed for Coca-Cola for a while, and their main brand colour is red. They're a very good example of how to apply red branding to websites and apps, if you're looking for one. They mainly use black, grey and white as their accent colours.

Comment: That caution message is scary. I'd definitely click 'Cancel'.

Comment: Actually, the question was so simple at the top, you need a good color for Danger action regarding your "red" application.

Actually, designing a new theme is another story, we try to help depend on the given requirements, from your input I can understand that even you have a problem in dealing with one color!

So, my suggestion is to include another color add to red let's say "Red and Black" as a primary color. and use gray color and all its degrees as secondary.

In this case, you can have space to play.

Answer (score 36):

One absolutely *key* thing to note here:

### Do not rely solely on colour to convey meaning.

Colours are handy for conveying a visual message, but you need to consider accessibility when making these kinds of UX decisions. If your user has any form of colour blindness or other visual impairment, you need some other kind of indicator (icons or wording) to convey the meaning. The fact that the button is titled `Delete` is great, but if you're concerned that it's 'system-critical' information, then that needs to be conveyed in way beyond simply using colour as an indicator.

[This article](https://uxplanet.org/heres-what-you-need-to-know-about-color-accessibility-in-product-design-aecbd0c30628) covers the use of colour with regards to accessibility, and has a paragraph specifically on this:

> "...ensure accessibility by making sure you don’t rely on color to
>   relay crucial system information. So, for things like error states,
>   success states, or system warnings, be sure to incorporate messaging
>   or iconography that clearly calls out what’s going on."

Also, considering that red is your app's key colour: ensure that you're using a contrast of at least `4.5:1` to adhere to [WCAG 2 level AA](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/) at a minimum. This is a really handy tool for checking that: https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/

Comment: Absolutely!  Apparently something approaching 2/3 of men have some sort of color misperception, and that doesn't even address people with low/nonexistent vision

Comment: Good call : this is the most important thing here : never rely on color to convey a meaning, as a quite big percentage of the population is color blind in various degrees (and culturally, colors may mean different things too). Always incorporate the meaning in several different ways (text + color + some symbol?)

Comment: @GeorgeM Approaching 2/3 of men? Do you have a citation for that? Wikipedia gives much lower figures. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness#Epidemiology

Comment: Right. I.e: What if the user is color blind?

Comment: I think OP is intending the color to be an *additional* channel supplementing the text which says what the action is.

Comment: @WBT Yep, totally get that, which is why I mention that `...[t]he fact that the button is titled Delete is great, but if you're concerned that it's 'system-critical' information, then that needs to be conveyed in way beyond simply using colour as an indicator.`

Comment: Rosie only about 10% of men have red-green color blindness.  But many more have more subtle/less inconvenient impairments.  When you throw in the very common blue/green confusion, the majority don't see color like they should.  Lots of fairly recent studies, just google

Answer (score 10):

As the number of viable options increases, it may become more difficult to make a final decision. Once you've narrowed it down to a few, you can **consider allowing users to select the scheme they prefer**.

Some color schemes to consider:

- Red = danger = your app is dangerous. **Change the main color of your app.**
- Blue = competitor's color. Competitor = dangerous. **Use blue for danger.** While a lighter blue may be mistaken for a positive alert (such as success), a dark blue may not.
- **Use black and white.** The examples in [Khalil Hanna's answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/125667/115162) are striking. The problem is black/white may be confused with ordinary text. Black + orange/yellow may not have the same problem.
- **Use standard colors** regardless the main color of your theme. Green = success. Yellow/Orange = Caution. Red = danger/warning. Etc.

  However, as [Aline points out](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/125665/115162), the [Google Material Design Color Usage](https://material.io/design/color/color-usage.html) advises: "Since red is a brand color, **don’t also use it to convey an error state**. Choose alternative alert colors that don’t use brand coloring." Their example uses orange. But purple seems a viable option as well.

  [image: Material Design Example]

Comment: Since I can't change the main color of my app because of the brand rules I think that I am going to go with the orange. Also, I'll try with the blue one as danger hehehe

Answer (score 5):

The "danger color" should stand out from the color scheme of your app. It is also good to consider meaning. Red/Orange/yellow, in most cultures, indicates danger, alert, attention. 
Usually, if I see a blue or green message, I automatically think it is a success feedback.
I think you should use orange or yellow, to stand out from the main colors.

In Google Material Design, they use orange with red themes: https://material.io/design/color/color-usage.html#meaning

Answer (score 5):

The first color scheme that comes to mind to indicate danger is a combination of yellow and black, particularly if the black is in diagonal stripes. I would suspect the association with danger comes from bees in nature.

Simply typing `yellow black sign` into Google will result in a lot of signs that indicate danger of some sort. Sings about poison, about danger of falling off, the tape used around crime scenes, etc.

I have personally seen message boxes with a thick, yellow and black diagonally striped border, and they always make me think there is something potentially dangerous, likely a possibly dangerous decision to be made. Seeing a button with a rounded triangle with the same pattern would tell me that I should be very cautious if I press that button.

To me, plain red is not actually as strong, and would need white and black to fully get across the same level of danger.

Answer (score 5):

If you are already using the colour red, then use yellow and black. It is a natural warning sign of nature, and will definitely draw attention. It is used also on many danger signs for construction sites.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In western countries, there is nothing culturally more dangerous than black on red:

[image]

Comment: What about yellow on red?

Comment: Or the trifecta...black & red, on yellow: https://www.123rf.com/photo_6253376_danger-symbol.html

Comment: @xiota I refer to the historical unconscious, I avoided putting the Nazi flag in the answer, I thought it would be implied

Comment: @Danielillo Then there's the not-yet historical conscious, which I also thought would be implied.

Comment: @Danielillo *"In western countries, there is nothing culturally more dangerous than black on red"* Do you have any source supporting this argument?  I believe that black on yellow background and white on red background are much more common than black on red background for [danger sign in western countries](https://www.google.com/search?q=danger+sign&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=lnt&tbs=itp:clipart).

Comment: @Daniello apart from yellow on red, maybe? Anyway, comparing the two  worst dictators of modern European history is way off-topic.

Comment: I like them! These icons are abstract and clear, I think this can work more like a separate sign, and for printed materials.

Comment: There are millions upon millions of unionists, social democrats, anarchists, Trotskyists, and Stalinists/Maoists in the "West" who have positive associations with red and black, which represents working-class power to them. It's the colour scheme of countless major brands, artistic works, designs and clothes. It's the colour of ladybugs and strawberries and watermelon and love hearts and the medical red cross.

Your context of "the West" is far too broad to be useful or meaningful. Colour associations are in no way as context-free, baked-in or hard-wired as you're assuming here.

Answer (score 1):

## GETTING ATTENTION

#### *COLOR LACKS MEANING*

Color alone does not convey meaning, and as such by itself it should not be relied on for any expression of "danger" or "warning." Further, visual impairments such as Deuteranomaly (6% of males affected) make certain color contrasts invisible, not to mention cultural differences as several have mentioned.

### CONTRAST, SYMBOLS, and TEXT

Colors such as red, yellow, orange were chosen not because the color has a specific meaning, but because the color provides a certain color contrast, luminance contrast, and "eye catch," and thus stands out against the background.

It is more important to have adequate luminance contrast, and to use attention/attraction oriented symbols that are clear in their intent.

**Luminance contrast** does not rely on color contrast which may be misperceived due to impairments or cultural differences, and helps the symbol to stand out. Using a higher luminance contrast than surrounding stimuli (text, buttons, etc.) is what will help gain attention and user focus.

**Color contrast** can help increase awareness in terms of cognitive recognition of a warning, but it must be a secondary design consideration. For instance, if the market is North America, **green** is possibly a bad choice for a warning — But green in combination with it's opponent color red (including purples) creates very strong edge detection in normal human visual perception.

**Understandable symbols** acan be very useful for conveying meaning in a way that (ideally) does not require translation. Though again cultural differences may have a strong influence.

In Las Vegas, the MGM Grand Hotel was originally designed where the front entrance was through a giant emerald colored lion's mouth. Shortly after opening thought, they tore it down and rebuilt the entrance to remove the lion's mouth because they discovered that a lion's mouth had a particularly negative symbolism in some asian cultures.

Within the realm of computers though, there are common icons that have attained an international acceptance of certain meanings — the well understood is typically the better choice, especially for conveying a warning.

**Text is king,** language differences notwithstanding. Clear and simple text is the best way to convey a specific meaning. A single word with a pop-up tool-tip of additional information is my personal preference for usability.

**Animation and motion** will affect attention if that is the goal. A single blinking red LED on a wall of 1000 red LEDs will surely grab your attention for instance.

## TL;DR

In short, it is more important to have good/high luminance contrast & descriptive text and symbols than any specific color combination.

Here's an example of using luminance contrast, a modification of your example delete button vs the save button:

[image: SAVE DELETE MODIFIED]

Answer (score 0):

Something to consider about creating User Interfaces is that **colour should never convey meaning**. However, you can highlight destructive buttons by making them different from other buttons or the rest of your interface. Instead of thinking about colours you could use, try thinking about how to make the button look *different*.

## Change the design

- **Borders** - If your current design has buttons with no border, try adding a very distinct (thick?) black or white border. This makes the button "pop" from the rest of the interface.
- **Size** - Try playing around with the height or width of the button. Size can help differentiate destructive buttons from normal buttons. But it doesn't always have to be about the size of the button, maybe you could change the font size of the label?
- **Font Style** - Talking about fonts, how about adding an underline, italic, or bold to the label to make it stand out?
- **Style** - Maybe add a shadow or only have borders and no fill colour. Play with the design and make it look *different*.

## Colours

Everyone's creative side varies, so if you do want to keep your current style but change the colours I would recommend looking at a colour wheel for colours that are opposite your reds. This will help make the button stand out. You can also emphasize the button by going for destructive colours like yellows, reds (obviously darker or lighter), black or white (if it suits your design.)

Design is a very challenging part of the development process, so playing around will definitely help. Get people's opinions - get them to choose a design. Make some mockup designs.
I hope this helped.